# MATLAB find references to function

Tags: matlab, call

MATLAB has some great tools, among which [this dependency listing function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.codetools.requiredfilesandproducts.html) stands out. I'm wondering, is there a way to perform the inverse operation?

That is, `fList = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts(files)` takes a function or script and returns a list of all of the dependencies. I am trying to do the opposite: given a function, I want to find all the functions where this function is called, perhaps limited to the scope of my working directory.

The only solution I can think of is a brute force approach (which would be *painfully* slow given the speed of `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`). In MATLAB-esque pseudocode:

```
foi = file of interest
files = empty set of file lists
i = 0;
for all files f in dir
    files{i} = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts(f);
    i = i + 1;
end
find indices in files where list contains foi
```

Surely there must be better way.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I have found is to use the MATLAB "find files" tool (in the latest versions, it is a button on the editor window).  It is actually extremely fast, and you can have it search all the .m files in a directory structure, and return every line where a particular string is used - like say, the name of your function.

Answer (score 1):

See if the **Parents** listing in the [dependency report](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html) is what you're looking for.  It only looks in the current directory, and it has some exclusions.